# Asp.net core 2.0 data migrations command failed

Tags: asp.net, ef-core-2.0

Getting an error while running migrations command.
I explored through the csproj file and itemgroup are in place but still getting the error.

csproj file attached for reference

[csproj file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wp8cX.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use either the Package Manager Console or the Command Line tool in the following manner:

```
    [Command Line]
    dotnet ef migrations add <name of migration>

    [Package Manager Console]
    add-migration <name of migration>
```